# Linking 2 fields in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

I'm new to OpenERP and not really getting how to do this.

What I need is a new field in the purchase requisition form called “project”. A user should be able to select to which project a quotation belongs. Then if the requisition is accepted and a quotation is formed this field should also be loaded to that form (with the correct project, that was selected on the requisition).

I’ve been reading a lot on the internet, but either can’t find the answer or I just don’t understand it.

I read some stuff about needing to create your own module to customize the forms, and found some step to step explanations. But then I still don’t get how to link the fields.

So if someone could give me an answer on how to do this, or direct me to an (easy to understand) explanation. That would be great.

Answer (score 0):

yes you should make a custom module for this. you will find enough tutorials on how to do that on the internet (e.g. http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/adding-additional-fields-using-custom-module-openerp-7).

in this custom module you have to extend the model purchase.order with one new field, call it like project_id. it will be a many2one type of field and so called other object (relation) will be either project.project or project.task.
after that you have to extend the form view (and maybe the tree view) of purchase.order (xml_id: purchase.purchase_order_form). just add your field where you want to have it ;-)

now get it done :-P i hope i could've helped you :-)

edited:

Ok, you if you got Admin rights on the OpenERP System you can try it the in-system-way. just open the models menu unter settings -> technical -> database structure

[image]

search for purchase.order and open the model form view. now edit the record and add a new field like (scroll down and click "add new item"):

[image]

now you have to create a new view, to extend the original one. go to settings -> technical -> user interface -> views.
create a new one like this:

[image]

that's it. if you open a purchase order, you will see the project field right under the supplier reference.

Comment: Well the problem is that I can't get onto the server to actually really change something/add a custom module (because of strange rules from the IT manager). So I am only able to change something with the debug screen/admin rights. As the OpenERP implementation is only a proof of concept at this point, I hoped these rights would be enough.

Comment: Thank you CZoellner, I'll try this tomorrow first thing in the morning. But when I've that field in the purchase order, is there also a way to "load" that data for example onto the invoice that follows from the PO?

Comment: for that you will need to override specific methods of the models, and as far as i know, only possible on code level :/